# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is the error message I get at Http Post method in Asp Mvc project from ajax.
I tried various ways to add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin for all the verbs like the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32642548/access-control-allow-origin-header-has-multiple-values-or-preflight-jquery-ajax) (which involved creating a WebApiConfig class and register it).

I have tried to add the following line in Web.conig too:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
```

but it didn't worked. I have tried with Attributes too like the following:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

And not all in the same timme, of course, and I don't know what am I missing.
The function in javascript i use for calling the post method is:

```
function CallAjax() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "http://localhost:51707/home/showthings/",
                data: {"data":"data"},
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    //things...
                    }
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(err.responseText);
                }
            });
```

The complete error message I get is this:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:51707/home/showthings/?data=. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:49491' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I think Your code will successfully run on server Did u try it? @meJustAndrew

Comment: I have tried it, and still getting the same error...